# Delete route in a nested resource in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a nested resources:

```
resources :bills do
  resources :debts
end
```

and when I make a delete link in the index html in the debts view like this:

```
<td>
   <%= link_to "Delete", [@bill, @debt], confirm: "Are you sure?", method: :delete %>
</td>
```

the bill is deleted, not the debt.
What happens?, How can I deleted only one debt of a specific Bill?
This is my delete action in my debt's controller.

```
def destroy
    @bill = Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
    @debt = @bill.debts.find(params[:id])
    @debt.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "The debt was successfully deleted"
    redirect_to bill_debts_url    
end
```

And my models:

Bill model:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :debts
end
```

Debt model:

```
class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: also, debt and bill are exactly the same (in the code you posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `has_many` association. If a `bill` `has_many` `debts`, then `bill.debts` is an association, not a single object. You need to call `destroy_all` on that object to destroy all of them:

```
def destroy
  @bill = Bill.find(params[:bill_id])
  @debts = @bill.debts.find(params[:id])
  @debts.destroy_all

  flash[:notice] = "The debt was successfully deleted"
  redirect_to bill_debts_url    
end
```

That being said, I'm not sure why the `Bill` is being destroyed at all...